# Assign ID to datatable row from json data

Tags: javascript, datatables

i'm new to datatable jquery plugin.
I got stuck with this for more than 2 days. I have a Json Data, i still cant load the table and i also want to assign first column to be id of the row

Here is html:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"
    id="accDetailTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Current/Savings Account No.</th>
            <th>Securities Account No.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my initialization

```
var oTable=$('#accDetailTable').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": contextPath + "/user/investorAjax?method=getInvestorAccDetailList",
            "iDeferLoading": 57,
    } );
```

Return jsonData from server :

```
    {"sEcho":1,"iColumns":4,"iTotalRecords":16,"iTotalDisplayRecords":16,
"aaData":
    [{"DT_RowId":2032,"currency":1,"currentAccNo":"aa","secureAccNo":"aa"},
    {"DT_RowId":2033,"currency":1,"currentAccNo":"111","secureAccNo":"111"},
    {"DT_RowId":2034,"currency":1,"currentAccNo":"a","secureAccNo":"aa"},
    ]}
}
```

But it always hit :

> DataTables warning (table id = 'accDetailTable'): Added data (size undefined) does not match known number of columns (3)

Comment: How about adding another hidden column to save the row id?

Comment: i try to add one more header <th> id</th> and set style of it to hidden. but it shows :  Added data (size undefined) does not match known number of columns (5).  From 3 it jumps to 5 , still dont know why

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of easy. Let's just do a tiny change, since you want the first column contains id, you may need to use fnRender, please [check the api of datatables](http://www.datatables.net/ref), I didn't add this part of code:

```
var oTable=$('#accDetailTable').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": contextPath + "/user/investorAjax?method=getInvestorAccDetailList",
    "aoColumns":[
        {"mDataProp":"currency"},
        {"mDataProp":"currentAccNo"},
        {"mDataProp":"secureAccNo"}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i try to config like this http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/ids.html : given the column data's name DT_RowId but it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I think the reason is your json data format, see the difference: "DT_RowId":2032 VS  "DT_RowId": "row_9", reference this: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8962/dt_rowid-not-adding-id-to-tr/p1

Comment: i try ur solution but still : Added data (size undefined) does not match known number of columns (3)

Comment: currently i cannot load the table.

Comment: The datatables can not recognize your data format I think, so you just have 3 ths while you provides 4 columns data.

Answer (score 0):

Your datatables is waiting for three entries per line and you give it four. In your table declaration (in html part) specify a new header cell `<th>` at the beginning of  your row. You will put ids in it. Then after your dataTables initialization you can hide the first column using `fnSetColumnVis(index, visibility)` function :

```
oTable.fnSetColumnVis(0, false); //It will hide your first column
```

Doing that each row is containing his id (DT_RowId) but not displaying it.

Comment: actually i try this http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/ids.html . It said that with DT_RowId property, datatable will automatically add it as Id of <tr>. I thought the error is not cause of JsonData.

Comment: In your given link, iColumns option isn't defined in json response. Can you try to remove it?

Comment: And adColumns definition in your dataTables initialization?

Comment: adColumns? can you give me an exp, i dont know about this prop

Comment: aoColumns sorry, try to remove it as it is not present in dataTables example